# Google Spreasheet API C#

Tags: google-sheets-api

***How to read the ranges from google spreadsheet using Named ranged using C# not other client-side scripts?***

This code contains the logic for inserting into the spreadsheet. Here the list inserted into google sheet blindly. But I would like to insert it based on the named range in google sheet and with that named range the columns need to be inserted.

```
 SheetsService SheetsService = GetSheetsService();
 string newRange = "WORKORDERTYPE";
 var namedRanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNamedRanges();               
 var StrReportJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
 JArray arrayJson = JArray.Parse(StrReportJson);
 List<IList<Object>> objNewRecords = new List<IList<Object>>();
 for (int i = 0; i < arrayJson.Count; i++)
 {
       IList<Object> obj = new List<Object>();
       JObject SingleObj = JObject.Parse(arrayJson[i].ToString());
       foreach (var pair in SingleObj)
       {    
            if(pair.Key.ToUpper()=="WORKORDERTYPE")
            obj.Add(pair.Value);
       }

       objNewRecords.Add(obj);
 }
SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest request = SheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Append((new ValueRange() { Values = objNewRecords }, SpreadSheetID, newRange);
request.InsertDataOption=SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.InsertDataOptionEnum.INSERTROWS;
request.ValueInputOption=SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
var response = request.Execute();
```

Comment: Writing to cells requires that you understand the concept of [A1 Notation first](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation) and actually know how to do [Basic Writing](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing).

Comment: I have practiced all the types. Here I would like to know how to get the ranges based on the NamedRange in google spreadsheet. I have named some columns based on that I have to take ranges and insert record using c#. In my code "WORKORDERTYPE" is a named range in google sheet. In that namedrange I have to take the ranges and then I have to insert the records..